# Softmax layer in Keras returns a vector of 1s

Tags: python, keras, softmax

I want to build a CNN in Keras with a softmax layer as an output, but I only get this as an output:

```
[[[[ 1.]
   [ 1.]
   [ 1.]]]]
```

My model is built like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(2, (1,3), padding='valid',
             input_shape=(3,3,50), init='normal', data_format='channels_first'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(20, (1,48), init='normal', data_format='channels_first'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(1, (1, 1), init='normal', data_format='channels_first', activation='softmax'))
```

I don't really get, why softmax does not work. Is it maybe because of a wrong input shape?

Answer (score 3):

The `softmax` activation will be applied to the last axis.

Looking at your `model.summary()`, your output shape is `(None, 3, 3, 1)`.

Having only one element at the last axis, your softmax output will always be 1 indeed.

You must select which axis you want to sum 1, and then reshape the output properly. For instance, if you want the softmax to consider the 3 channels, you need to move these channels to the final position:

```
#your last convolutional layer, without the activation: 
model.add(Conv2D(3, (1, 1), kernel_initializer='normal', data_format='channels_first'))

#a permute layer to move the channels to the last position:
model.add(Permute((2,3,1)))

#the softmax, now considering that channels sum 1.
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

But if your purpose is that the entire result sums 1, then you should add a `Flatten()` instead of a `Permute()`.

---

Keras seems to be more suited to working with `channels_last`. In this case, the softmax would automatically be applied to channels, without extra work needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with your model architecture. If you look at some of the popular models:

- https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py
- https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/cifar10_cnn.py

You will find out that the structure for a CNN usually looks like this:

1. Some convolutional layers with relu activation
2. A pooling layer (i.e. max pooling, mean pooling, etc.)
3. Flat the convolution layer
4. A dense layer
5. Then, a softmax

It does not make sense to apply a softmax to a convolutional layer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding a dense layer after the convolutional layer, but without to flatten it. Now it works!

Comment: Softmax in convolutional layers (channels summing 1) is a good idea for image segmentation tasks, where each channel is a class.

Comment: For pixel classification, Uber seems to have used softmax in their last conv layer: https://eng.uber.com/coordconv/ . I am using an open source Keras implementation. Will flattening still retain the spatial coordinate information?